# Plotting the function with DiracComb as a component

Tags: plotting

I'm interested in plotting the absolute value sqaured of the product of the Fourier transforms of a DiracComb and a phase function (exponent with complex argument).

```
Abs[FourierTransform[DiracComb[x/2.5]],x,ν]*FourierTransform[Exp[-I 2 π x Tan[45 * π / 180]],x,ν]]^2
```

Searching similar questions showed how to fake DiracDelta plots, but not to do so for DiracComb plots.

Comment: A serious math reference to "The Fourier transform of DiracComb is a DiracComb " ,as MMA documentation claims, would be useful in connection with the question under consideration.